# Replacing a value at a particular position from a file with another value from another file

Tags: bash, sed

We had two files, one with values filled with zeroes from position 61 to 67, and the other with the counter for this from position 1 to 7.
We needed to replace this counter from the second file to the first one.
Replacing a string in a file could be done via

```
sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.txt
```

But for particular position how to replace and to take from another file positions could someone help.

File 1 which needs to be changed *e.g.*:

```
10300109300109300109300009806200000012345678912345021 00000000000000123456789                                                                   
23000000201093001093011100000485806212345678912345021 00000000000000123456789                                     
23000000601093001093011100002225409112345678912345021 00000000000000123456789 
10300109300109300109300009806200000012345678912345021 00000000000000123456789
```

Counter Numbers File *e.g.*:

```
11122233333
1224555
12223323
12245555
```

Code Tried:

```
echo File Name: "$1"
echo Number File Name: "$2"
filename="$1"
numberfilename="$2"
echo $numberfilename
if [ ! -f "$numberfilename" ]
then
    echo "$0: File '${numberfilename}' not found."
elif [ ! -f "$filename" ]
then
    echo "$0: File '${filename}' not found."
else
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a numbers < $numberfilename

    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a records < $filename

    i=0
    while read record; do
        sed 's/^\(.\{61\}\)0000000/\${numbers[i]:0:7}/'
        echo "${record}"
    ((i=i+1))
    done < $filename

  fi
```

Expected Output:

```
10300109300109300109300009806200000012345678912345021 00000011122230123456789                                                                   
23000000201093001093011100000485806212345678912345021 00000012245550123456789                                     
23000000601093001093011100002225409112345678912345021 00000012223320123456789 
10300109300109300109300009806200000012345678912345021 00000012245550123456789
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus hopefully this explains what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { counter[NR]=substr($0, 1, 6); next }
  { printf("%-62.62s%06i%s\n", $0, counter[++i], substr($0, 68)) }' "$numberfilename" "$filename"
```

More generally, you don't want to use `while read; do` ... when `sed` and Awk already provide the same functionality, and usually run much faster (and also avoid brittleness problems with your current code; read up on `read -r` etc).

The `NR==FNR` Awk idiom is a common way to read the first file into memory, then process the second (the condition will be true when you read the first file, and false when you process the second, and so you fall through to after the `next`).

In some more detail, we collect the numbers into an array `counter`, then inject the values from the array as we proceed through the second file.

Demo: https://ideone.com/Ofztu3

Comment: Thanks @tripleee but I am not so great at scripting, was not able to understand how you are fetching the numbers from the numberfile. I tried adding this to my script and it printed out the input file without any changes. I have attached my solution too.

Comment: The code wrks for me locally. A common beginner issue is if your data contains DOS carriage returns, though I'm guessing that's not the problem here.

Comment: Updated with a small fix, an explanation, and a demo link.

Comment: `++i` could just be `FNR`. I think you're off by a couple of 0s btw - I'd have expected your print statement to be something like `printf "%s%06d%s\n", substr($0,1,60), counter[FNR], substr($0,68)`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (*GNU* `sed`):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/cat file2/e;x};G;s/^(.{60}).{7}([^\n]*)\n(.{7}).*/\1\3\2/;x;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x' file1
```

Copy the entirety of *file2* into the hold space on the first line of *file1*.

Append the hold space (*file2*) to each line of *file1*.

Using regexp and back references, replace position 61 to 67 by the first 7 characters of the hold space (*file2*).

Remove the first line of the hold space (*file2*), print the result and repeat.

Alternative, using `paste`:

```
paste file1 file2 | sed -E 's/^(.{60}).{7}(.*)\t(.{7}).*/\1\3\2/'
```

*N.B.* `paste` uses a *tab* as the default delimiter.

Comment: The `paste` version is much cleaner, and would make a better lead answer.  The `cat` version is inefficient, particularly if *file2* is large, as `x` and `G` would be always swapping a large (gradually diminishing) buffer to and fro.

Answer (score -1):

This is the working solution for me, not an optimized one though:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Record File Name: "$1"
echo Numbers File Name: "$2"
recordFileName="$1"
NumberFileName="$2"

if [ ! -f "$NumberFileName" ] 
then
    echo "$0: File '${NumberFileName}' not found."
elif [ ! -f "$recordFileName" ] 
then
    echo "$0: File '${recordFileName}' not found."
else
#Fetching numbers from numbers file
    IFS=$'\n' read -d "" -r -a numbers < "$NumberFileName"
    echo "${#numbers[@]} numbers fetched"
    IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a records < "$recordFileName"
    echo "${#records[@]} Records fetched"

    if [ ${#records[@]} -ge ${#records[@]} ]
    then

    #Counter initialized
        i=0
    #Clearing the final file if already present
       > "${recordFileName%.*}_final.dat"

    #Loop to replace the characters to replace the numbers fetched
        while read -r record; do
            if [ "${record:0:1}" = 2 ] 
            then
                var1=${record:0:61}
                var2=${record:68}   
                var3=${numbers[i]:0:7}
                echo "$var1$var3$var2" >> "${recordFileName%.*}_final.dat"
            else
                var4=${record:0}
                echo "$var4" >> "${recordFileName%.*}_final.dat"
            fi
            ((i = i + 1))
        done < "$recordFileName"
        echo "Numbers replaced to final file ${recordFileName%.*}_final.dat"
    else     
        echo "Numbers Count less than Records count."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the bugs it tells you about. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for reasons why not to do use this approach at all though and see [@triplee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341197/1745001) for the right approach.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for the shellchecker will fix the issues. But the looping I have done just to make it easier for the user I am sending to understand make changes easily at their end.

Comment: There is no way that 50-line (or whatever it is) convoluted shell script (which btw contains bugs that shellcheck won't tell you about) is easier to understand or modify than the equivalent (but more robust, portable, and efficient) couple of lines of awk.